# How do I match multiple values for array data types in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Considering the following data set, how would I match on multiple values of the same field?

```
{
  "description": "My first description.",
  "tags": ["A", "B", "C"]
},
{
  "description": "My second description.",
  "tags": ["A", "D", "E"]
}
```

In the above, I would like to create a query that matches on records with "tags" of "A" *and* "B".  I'm currently using something similar to the following:

```
query: {
  terms: {
    tags: ["A", "B"]
  }
}
```

However, this will return both records, as it's matching on *any* of the values.  Is there any ability to keep this dynamic (pass in array of values) and return results that include all of the "tags"?

Comment: Don't have elasticsearch to check it now, but this query should work `{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"term": {"tags": "A"}},
        {"term": {"tags": "B"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Did it resolved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Since version 6.1, you can use the `terms_set` query (see [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-set-query.html)), which allows you to write your query as follows:

```
{
  "query": {
    "terms_set": {
      "score": {
        "tags": ["A","B"],
        "minimum_should_match_script": {
          "source": "2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```